# How to rank within a group with tie breakers in excel

Tags: excel

I have data split out into groups with scores and earnings assigned to each. I want to rank within each group based on score. If there is a tie in score, I want to use earnings as a tie breaker. I know I can rank with a tie breaker with the following formula:

```
=RANK.EQ(C3,$C$3:$C$13) + COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$13,C3,$D$3:$D$13,">"&D3)
```

But this would rank all of the scores, not just by group.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$13=B3)*($C$3:$C$13+$D$3:$D$13/100>=C3+D3/100))
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the "/100" for the earnings column?

Comment: I suppose you could replace the 100 with MAX($D$3:$D$13)+1 to be on the safe side if one row had earnings over $99.

Comment: @brightman1309 it makes the value a decimal then we can rank on the two summed.  If your values exceed two digits you can just increase to `1000` or even `1000000` it will work.